# How to compute partial correlation analysis, particularly spearman's pca?

Tags: r

I've tried to follow the instruction from the pcor.test manual (found here http://www.yilab.gatech.edu/pcor.html), but the error came up

```
Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

What's wrong?

I initially used my own data which is imported from SPSS

```
pcor.test(a$Pexposed, a$w0, a$CAI, method = "spearman", na.rm = T)
```

but the output is like the following

```
Error in pcor.test(a$Pexposed, a$w0, a$CAI, method = "spearman", na.rm = T) : 
  unused argument(s) (method = "spearman", na.rm = T)
```

What's going on here? It seems that pcor.test is not for newbie user?
Thanks for any help.

PS:
Here's my data.

```
Pexposed=c(1:10)
w0=c(3:12)
CAI=c(2:11)
a=data.frame(Pexposed=Pexposed,w0=w0,CAI=CAI)
```

Comment: Please post your data, or a subset of it, or at least show the error with mocked-up data.  You most likely have your variables encoded wrong.

Comment: @Dirk, I've just made the mocked-up dataset (I put it under PS in my original post), and started over the pcor.test, but I got just the same error. Btw, my real dataset was imported from Excel. And if the errors were the same, chances are my real imported dataframe were encoded the same as the mocked-up dataset. Well, I am not quite sure I got what you mean by wrong encoding here. I'm newbie in R, sorry. Thank you. PS: Do you know why I don't have notification from stackoveflow yet? That's why I just visited this page and saw someone already commented on my post.

Comment: @Rivo Suoth - I can't reproduce any of your errors with the data you provided in the question. It runs for me (with a warning, since your example data are all perfectly correlated).

Comment: @joran, I don't know why the errors keep happening. This is the only stat test that produces such the error. I have no problem with *cor.test* btw.

Comment: SOLVED :), I am so sorry I skipped the code **source("pcor.R")**. Btw, if one wants to activate source("pcor.R"), download and put this first in working directory (Btw, any other suggestion?). Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because you gave a non-numerical vector to the function.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the downvote!  Yes, maybe I should have asked for you to edit and put your data... So, yes, there are no "na.rm" argument to this function (see:  ?pcor.test ). Then, even if you remove this argument, well, the partial correlation give a crazy result, because your test data is bad. Indeed, you probably did not try yourself, otherwise you will notice that correcting the effect of a variable that correlate with r=1 from a correlation with r=1 is just insane. Please provide some real data, since no one can reproduce your error.